# How to use private key and public key with chain in a mutual ssl authentication

Tags: ssl, openssl, postman, mutual-authentication

I'm facing with a problem with mutual ssl authentication. 
I have generated a csr and a private key, I gave the csr to the our customer CA that signed it and gave me back the certificate/public key with the a chain inside. 
When I try to communicate with the server that require mutual SSL , using that certificate chain and my private key I have an error because the private key does not match the certificate. I'm using postman to do the call and I'm using openssl to verify the modulus :

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.pem
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in privateKey.key
openssl req -noout -modulus -in csr.csr
```

The last two match but the first one no. If I extract the single certificate from the chain the modulus will match but the resulting certificate, without chain,  is not a trusted certificate but a self-signed one. 
What I'm loosing, what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure there is something missing.

THanks to all.

Comment: Did you try to verify each certificate from the chain using `openssl verify`?

Comment: Yes, I did with this command :  openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem  certificate.cer with this output : certificate.cer: OK

Comment: At this stage I can only think that the certificate generation went wrong, because the public key of the CSR must match its related certificate. You say there is an error _because the private key does not match the certificate_, how sure are you about this? What is the exact error code? Did you try with `openssl s_client`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. What I did to check if the public key match the certificate is comparing his modulus . If I extract the single certificate from the chain the modulus are the same. I'm sure that the certificate generation is right because they are doing it every day.